# Android Fragments Issue

Tags: android

Ok Im trying to download some xml and am using fragments. I have got a source not found error and believe there is something up with my code. The logcat is producing no errors the app shuts down as soon as it is opened here is my main fragment

```
 package com.paad.earthquake;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class EarthquakeListFragment extends ListFragment {

 ArrayAdapter<Quake> aa;
 ArrayList<Quake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Quake>();

 @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
aa = new ArrayAdapter<Quake>(getActivity(), layoutID , earthquakes);
setListAdapter(aa);

refreshEarthquakes();
  }

  private static final String TAG = "EARTHQUAKE";
   private void refreshEarthquakes() {
    // Get the XML
     URL url;
    try {
      String quakeFeed = getString(R.string.quake_feed);
      url = new URL(quakeFeed);

    URLConnection connection;
  connection = url.openConnection();

  HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
  int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

  if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    // Parse the earthquake feed.
    Document dom = db.parse(in);
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

    // Clear the old earthquakes
    earthquakes.clear();

    // Get a list of each earthquake entry.
    NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("entry");
    if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element entry = (Element)nl.item(i);
        Element title = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);
        Element g = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("georss:point").item(0);
        Element when = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("updated").item(0);
        Element link = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);

        String details = title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String hostname = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov";
        String linkString = hostname + link.getAttribute("href");

        String point = g.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String dt = when.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date qdate = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
        try {
          qdate = sdf.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Date parsing exception.", e);
        }

        String[] location = point.split(" ");
        Location l = new Location("dummyGPS");
        l.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(location[0]));
        l.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(location[1]));

        String magnitudeString = details.split(" ")[1];
        int end =  magnitudeString.length()-1;
        double magnitude = Double.parseDouble(magnitudeString.substring(0, end));

        details = details.split(",")[1].trim();

        Quake quake = new Quake(qdate, details, l, magnitude, linkString);

        // Process a newly found earthquake
             addNewQuake(quake);
          }
        }
       }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "IOException", e);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Parser Configuration Exception", e);
} catch (SAXException e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "SAX Exception", e);
}
finally {
}
  }

    private void addNewQuake(Quake _quake) {
     // Add the new quake to our list of earthquakes.
      earthquakes.add(_quake);

        // Notify the array adapter of a change.
       aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

Here is my main java class

```
package com.paad.earthquake;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

   public class Earthquake extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }

}
```

And here is my main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <fragment 
  android:name="com.paad.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/EarthquakeListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I also have a helper class but I dont think you will have to see that. Any help is appreciated. Log cat is throwing no exceptions dont even know where to start looking on this one.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.paad.earthquake"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Earthquake"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you added the support library?

Comment: I am slightly confused on what you mean by support library. I ahve downloaded all the add ons from google. Is there something special for fragments?

Comment: Are you testing on a JellyBean device?

Comment: Because your using support.v4.. I thought you might need to download the support library. If you're using eclipse, just right click on the project and click 'add support libratry'.. I have no idea if this will solve your problem though (hence why it's a comment and not an answer)

Comment: I was able to get it working thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In my experience closing directly after launch without a stack trace usually means that there is a problem with your AndroidManifest.xml file.  Do you have your main activity declared in the manifest?

If you do , can you post that here as well?

Comment: hmm.. no problems there.  Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: Its not throwing any errors which is why its so weird. The log cat doesnt say anything I just get the infamous source not found attach a source. Maybe im missing some source needed for fragments. Ive tried it on my phon which is api 10 and on the emulator which is api16

Comment: ok log cat has yellow warning saying unable to resolve superclass com/paad/EarthquakeListFragment

Comment: Is your device running the latest Android version?  I think FragmentActivity is new in 16?

Comment: was missing a handler import and handler line of code at the bottom. Thought I had copied it but forgot. Also it only works on android 4.0 and 4.1 which is important to note